# $\{S_n\}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2$

Tags: probability-theory, lp-spaces, martingales

> Given $\{X_i\}$ independent nonnegative r.v.'s such that for all $n ≥ 1$ we have that $E[X_n] = 1,\forall n$, define $M_n:=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_k$ and the filtration $\mathcal F_n=\sigma(X_1,\dots, X_n)$

If $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} E(\sqrt{M_k})>0$ then show that $\{S_n\}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2$, where $S_k:=\sqrt{M_k}$

So I need $E\left((S_n-S_m)^2\right)<\epsilon$ for certain $N\le m\le n$ large enough

Set $a_k:=E(\sqrt{X_k})$ then if $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}E(\sqrt{M_k})>0\iff$ $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-a_k)<\infty$

So $a_k\uparrow 1$ with growing $k$, then

$E\left((S_n-S_m)^2\right)=E\left(M_n+M_m-2S_mS_n\right)=2E(M_m)-2E(M_m\prod\limits_{k=m+1}^{n}\sqrt{X_k})$

$=2E(M_m)-2E(M_m)\prod\limits_{k=m+1}^{n}E(\sqrt{X_k})$

and this not going to lead anywhere ?

Comment: As $L_p$ are complete you need to show that $M_n$ converges in $L_1$. $M_n$ is a nonnegative martingale, hence it converges a.s., maybe this helps.

Comment: @mbartczak the whole thing is to show the converse, i.e. $S_n$ is Cauchy in $L^2$ so is $M_n$ in $L^1$ (there is an inequality here to ensure that), but $L^1$ is complete so $M_n$ cv in $L^1$